# IconToolbarItem with Iconize not click event

Tags: xamarin

I am currently developing a Xamarin.Forms application.  I am using [IconizePlugin](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize).  The app is tabbedPage based and on toolbar I'm trying to include icons for some actions.

This is whay I'm getting:
[image]

Icons are showing well and in Xamarin.iOS gets the click event, while it is not working in Xamarin.Droid.

I included the corresponding nugets and followed every steps told in documentation and can't archive this.  Other iconize controls in Droid are working fine except the IconToolbarItem.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I found was to declare de IconToolbarItem in the c# code instead of xaml.  Although I don't know why it wasn't working while on xaml.

Declaring the item li

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new IconToolbarItem
{
       Icon = "fa-plus",
       IconColor = Color.White,
       Command = new Command(this.addBono)
});
```